# How do I work on a branch in SVN Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I've read multiple documentations already but I don't seem to get it - I want to branch one project folder of our rcp, change something there and test with the changes I've made there.

Which steps do I have to make to work on the branch? How do I integrate the branch in my workspace for testing without ruining my local files and what does Switch... do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on a branch directly through Subclipse isn't possible. You have to check out to your local machine first and then commit back.

This will override local changes, so make sure to branch them first.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to test your quick changes in your project without your local changes ,this is what you can do

1. -Create a new branch of the trunk/active of your project in SVN
2. -Checkout the new branch from SVN as its own project
3. make your quick change . Test it locally
4. Check it back into the branch. When you are ready, merge your code.